# Escaping reserved url parameters in Java

Tags: java, android

I am building an Android app and there is a part of the app where I need to post to a url with some form data. One of the form fields I pass along is an email address.

I noticed an issue where some email addresses have a '+' sign in them which is a reserved character in URLs that means ' '. I wanted to know, how can I sanitize/escape characters like this and others in my code before I convert it to a post byte[]. I don't want to do a replaceAll. Is there a specific encoder built into Java that will do this?

Here is the code I use:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append(ID + "=" + params.id + "&");
builder.append(LOCALE + "=" + params.locale + "&");
builder.append(EMAIL + "=" + params.getEmail());

String encodedParams = builder.toString();
mWebView.postUrl(URL, EncodingUtils.getAsciiBytes(encodedParams));
```

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your problem, but a + typically means ignore the + and everything after it for the username part of the email.  For example, bob.smith+mailing_list_1@gmail.com goes to bob.smith@gmail.com but is useful for signing up for sites when you want to easily filter messages sent to your address.

Answer (score 2):

Try using java.net.URLEncoder.encode(valueToEncode, "UTF-8");

It's been a while since I've looked at the details, but I believe you have to call encode() on the individual parts of the string before you concatenate them.

The utility method below has been working well for me:

```
    /**
     * Given a {@link Map} of keys and values, this method will return a string
     * that represents the key-value pairs in
     * 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' MIME format.
     * 
     * @param keysAndValues
     *            the keys and values
     * @return the data in 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' MIME format
     */
    private String wwwFormUrlEncode(Map<String, String> keysAndValues) {
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            boolean isFirstEntry = true;
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> argument : keysAndValues.entrySet()) {
                if (isFirstEntry) {
                    isFirstEntry = false;
                } else {
                    sb.append("&");
                }
                sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(argument.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                sb.append("=");
                sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(argument.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            //it is unlikely that the system does not support UTF-8 encoding, 
            //so we will not bother polluting the method's interface with a checked exception
            throw new RuntimeException(e); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace plus sign with %2b . you must encode it in order to use it in url or else it will be considered as space. then in your server side you can html decode emails.

Comment: How can I do this without explicitly having to replace strings. There should be some way to do this built into the java framework no?

Comment: builder.append(EMAIL + "=" + TextUtils.htmlEncode(params.getEmail()));